# http.HandleFunc always match "/"

Tags: http, go

Code:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", api.Index)
http.HandleFunc("/list", api.FileList)

http.HandleFunc("/api/upload", api.UploadFile)
http.HandleFunc("/api/delete", api.DeleteFile)

http.Handle("/files", http.StripPrefix("/files/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(settings.FilesPath))))

http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil)
```

Result 1:

http://localhost:1234/

http://localhost:1234/list

http://localhost:1234/files

> match "/"
>
> api.index (It's wrong for the second and third)

Result 2:

http://localhost:1234/api/upload

http://localhost:1234/api/delete

> match "/api/xxx"
>
> api.xxx (It's right)

env:

go 1.13.5 windows/amd64

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: The code show is unlikely to show the described bbehaviour. What is wrong: You should use `http.Handle("/files/", ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use "/list/" replace "/list"

more information: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http?tab=doc#ServeMux